# How can I pass selected rows from a lightning data table and display in a differnt component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, lightning-datatable

I have a component with a data table. I am able to get the selected rows in an object. I am trying to pass it to a different component using the application event. The event fires but it doesn't display the passed attributes on a different component.
Here is the Event:

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template">
    <aura:attribute name="selectedProvidersList" type="List" access="GLOBAL"/>

</aura:event>
```

The first component firing the event and its the js

```
   <!--Register Provider Select Event-->
        <aura:registerEvent name="selectProv" type="c:SelectProviders"/>
 <!--SELECTED ROWS-->
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRowsDetail" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRows" type="List"/>  <!--This is selectedRows -->
    <aura:attribute name="selectedSearchableList" type="List"/> <!--This is a list of all rows selected-->

    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Next" onclick="{!c.selectProviders}"></lightning:button>
```

controller:

```
updateSelectedProviders : function(component, event, helper){
        var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
        console.log('Selected rows '+selectedRows);
        let obj =[];
        for(var i =0; i<selectedRows.length; i++){
            obj.push(selectedRows[i]);
            console.log('Selected rows name '+selectedRows[i].Id);
            //Here you can get all the needed fields output and print on the next page
        }
        component.set("v.selectedSearchableList", obj);



    },

    selectProviders : function(component, event, helper){
        var evt = $A.get("e.c:SelectProviders");
        evt.setParams({
            "selectedProvidersList" : component.get("v.selectedSearchableList")
        });

        console.log('Event fired');
        evt.fire();
}
```

The target componnet where I am trying to display the output:

```
<aura:attribute name="myProviders" type="List"/>
 <!--calling event-->
    <aura:handler  event="c:SelectProviders" action="{!c.getSelectedProviders}" />

<aura:iteration items="myProviders" var="provider">
        {!provider.id}
</aura:iteration>
```

controller.js

```
getSelectedProviders : function(component, event) {
        var showResultsData = event.getParam("selectedProvidersList");
        component.set("v.myProviders",showResultsData );
        console.log('Event here'+component.get("v.myProviders"));
        console.log('Event parama'+JSON.stringify(showResultsData));
    }
```

Comment: Does the other component receive the event at all? If it does, what's the delta between the received parameters and the expected values?

Comment: Yes It does I am able to see the console logs for the parameters passed. I am getting the same values that I am expecting but it doesnt show in the aura iteration component but shows in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a case sensitivity issue. In the sending component, you have:

```
    let obj =[];
    for(var i =0; i<selectedRows.length; i++){
        obj.push(selectedRows[i]);
        console.log('Selected rows name '+selectedRows[i].Id);
```

Note the case if `selectedRows[i].Id`.

But in the receiving component, you have

```
<aura:iteration items="myProviders" var="provider">
        {!provider.id}
</aura:iteration>
```

Aura and JavaScript are case-sensitive, so you'll need to use `.Id` here too.

Additionally, [`<aura:iteration>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:iteration/example) needs a binding:

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.myProviders }" var="provider">
```

to get access to the component attribute.

Comment: Event parama[{"Id":"003f000001NlUP2AAN","AccountId":"001f000001PNdE9AAL","Is_Referrable__c":false,"Name":"George A. Taylor",...  This is the console log. And I changed the id to Id still didnt work.

Comment: I have wrong syntax for aura iteration items  items="{!v.myProviders}"

Comment: I think it's the missing bind on the `items` attribute, @P.Shri.

Answer (score 0):

There was a wrong syntax in aura iteration:
(missed v.)

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.myProviders}" var="provider">
        {!provider.id}
</aura:iteration>
```